# Question was closed by people without expertise in the subject

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I recently asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33017094/set-a-base-uri-for-api) about compiling process in extjs related to a base url for a remote api. The question was closed because it was deemed "opinion based".

This puzzled me a lot: this is a precise technical question about the internals of the sencha framework compilation and i don't see how can opinions have something to do with that.

Then I looked at the profile of the people that voted for closing the question and i saw that they are all javascript programmers but no one shows any particular experience in extjs programming. This make sense: the same question related to general javascript programming is a "too broad" and "opinion based" question because you have a lot of choices depending on your framework and infrastructure. This is not true in extjs environment where you have to work with what Sencha provides you.

Here the problem is - i think - not that my question is ill written (apart from the title maybe) because if some well versed extjs programmer reads it, he immediately understadns what i'm talking about. The problem is that people without the proper technical background that could not understand the question, decided that it was wrong.

What can I do to prevent similar future problems in the future?

Comment: Are you serious? I mean, that "gracefully" stands for "a solution better than mantaining five different code versions for one line of code" that should be implicit in the problem.

Comment: I nominated it for re-opening, it seems pretty legit to me.

Comment: It may still get closed as "too broad" - I'd lose "gracefully", and be *very* specific about where/how you'd like to retrieve and use the API base once the ideal working solution has been found -- preferably showing some idealized sample code. That would increase both the likelihood of an answer, and the quality of the answers you *do* get. Even for someone with Sencha knowledge, what's obvious to you might not be obvious to all.

Comment: People take things very literally here on SO. Even as someone who takes things quite literally myself, I get surprised every now and then. You'll just have to get used to it.

Comment: p.s. I also voted to reopen.

Comment: Your question is phased as if it's asking a very general design question.  If you *actually* want an answer to a very specific particular design that you're having trouble implementing, then changing your question to ask *that* would make it on topic on SO.

Comment: Note that the technical expertise of the close voter seems pretty irrelevant here.  Your question was closed because either it really is a very broad question, or because you phrased it in such a way that most readers (regardless of technical expertise) are misinterpreting it.  Either way, it merits closure until you can fix those problems.

Comment: If you are asking a very general design question in a context where there's a framework that handles that kind of deisgn problem, then it's not a very general question anymore. "How do i add two numbers" is a general question, "How do i add two numbers using python 3.0.4" is not a general question. Since sencha-cmd handles the compilation of an extjs app, this is not a question about design choices, this is a question about sencha app configuration, and i fail to see how that can be matter of opinion.

Comment: "this is not a question about design choices, this is a question about sencha app configuration" where's your configuration?  What have you tried to accomplish your goal? Why is it not working?

Comment: I've tried looking for a way to do that and i didn't find it. It's not working because i've got no clue of how to make it work. Therefore my configuration is the standard configuration of a brand new sencha app.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not what was asked, it's *how* it was asked.

Trigger language for closing as 'primarily opinion based':

- best
- how can I do this better
- favorite
- tips
- best practices
- common ways

Why are these trigger words? Because all of these involve tradeoffs that can't be fully seen by anyone other than the people who have the full knowledge of what you're working on.

Why is that a problem?

Well, what's 'best' for you may not be helpful at all to someone else; or may not work because of their constraints.  Instead of frustrating end users with answers that may not work, we want to be sure our answers can work *objectively*, and that means staying away from opinion-based questions.

This question is not 'primarily opinion based'.  It is, however, a very vaguely written question.

In this case, the question has a few problems that probably lent to it being closed:

- Too much filler text, not enough substance (see bolded parts):

  > **I'm starting to develop a new extjs 6 application and I'm confronted with a recurring (for me) problem for which I never found a proper working solution.**
  >
  > **Let say** that my application is hosted at www.myapp.com and get its data from api.myapp.com. Then I have a test version at test.mayapp.com with api located at api.test.myapp.com. Finally i have a development version on my computer, **let say** localhost:1841 (sencha app watch default) and the api at localhost:6543 (pyramid default).
  >
  > **How can i gracefully handle this scenario? I cannot hardcode these parameters, of course**. **My idea would be to be able to do** "sencha build app {someparameter}" **in a way that would produce** a compiled version **suited for this or that purpose but so far** I didn't find a single way to do that.

The best questions have very little filler text and the maximum amount of information. Here's the actual information from that question:

- The *actual* information doesn't pop in the question:

  > I have three environments I deploy my app to: localhost (development), test.myapp.com (test), and live (myapp.com) with an API located at  `api.` for each environment as well. How do I deploy to all three without hardcoding links to each environment?
- It took me three reads of that question to figure out that's what the OP was asking for. And even here, that's a *best guess*.

The *gracefully* clued people that there was something wrong with it that they could pin a close vote on, but the real reason that question was closed is that it's unclear.

The best thing you can do when you see a question closed is to help fix the question.  Posting to meta helps when there's nothing wrong with the question; but most of the time what a closed question needs is a good edit.

Comment: You beat me to it.  My alternate question version was going to be: "How do I pass relevant parameters to my sencha build command line, and then use those parameters to handle building the application for the development or test environment, without hardcoding the paths?", but I think yours is better. Mine may be too broad.

Comment: Hehe, you said "trigger".

Comment: @BoltClockI don't get it.